# Why does my DataGridView resist displaying the bottom data and how do I fix it?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, scrollbars

I have a form with a DataGridView.  I format it like this:

```
dgvECN.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None
dgvECN.Columns(0).Width = 50
...
dgvECN.Columns(15).Width = 100
dgvECN.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
```

The grid always has more data than will appear on one screen, so I rely on scrollbars -- primarily the vertical.  If I grab the scrollbar with the mouse and drag it as far down as it will go, it stops maybe ~97% of the way down the bar, as if I'd reached the bottom and there are more rows of data that I haven' not yet scrolled to.  I can release the scrollbar and grab it again and drag it down and it will go down further, but not all the way.  On the fourth try (with the current data), it reaches the bottom.

I can hold down the down-arrow at the bottom of the scroll-bar and that works.  I can cursor/arrow down or page-down all the way to the bottom.  When I do any of those things, the scroll-handle jitters down and then up a little like it's recalculating or something.

I have tried having the form load with the bottom of the data showing by using:

```
dgvECN.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvECN.RowCount - 1
```

But that scrolls the view to around the region of data where the grid seems to initially think the bottom is, rather than the actual bottom.

I *think* this is my first time working with wrapping text inside the grid's cells, so I suspect that as a cause.

But I've been reading and reading and while I've found plenty of exotic bugs and errors that sound related at first, they all end up not being my issue and I haven't found anything that fixes it.

Feel free to ask in the comment for specific info about my project, I'm not sure what you might need to help diagnose this.  And thanks for your time!

ETA: .NET 4.0 and VS Express 2013, in case it matters.

ETA2: I've attempted to set the on-load display so that it's showing the bottom of the data rather than that top.  I'm doing this with:

```
dgvECN.CurrentCell = dgvECN.Item(0, dgvECN.Rows.Count - 1)
```

But that doesn't actually take it to the bottom of the data.  I imagine this is a manifestation of the same error.

ETA3: This is what it looks like when it loads with the current cell set to the bottom row:
[image: bugged DataGridView]

ETA4: the DataGridView Designer code:

```
    '
    'dgvECN
    '
    Me.dgvECN.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Me.dgvECN.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    Me.dgvECN.AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
    Me.dgvECN.Anchor = CType((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.dgvECN.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    Me.dgvECN.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
    Me.dgvECN.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.dgvECN.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.Check})
    Me.dgvECN.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
    Me.dgvECN.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
    Me.dgvECN.Name = "dgvECN"
    Me.dgvECN.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1102, 670)
    Me.dgvECN.TabIndex = 5
```

Comment: i'm not sure you can. never tried it but my assumption is that the rowHeight is calculated from the default or minimum when sizing the scrollbar. so what happens when you get to the end is it just adds x number of rows to the scrollbar that are below. but if there are any wrapped rows there too, before the end, it'll prob stop again, and update again, etc... you may be able to set a static rowHeight, but that's ugly... or maybe somehow calculate the heights of all the rows manually, and update... not sure if possible, PITA in any case.

Comment: Yes, it *feels* to me like it must be related to that as well.  But I just can't believe there isn't a 'correct' way to do this.

Comment: well, you could set the last record as the current record, and then set it back to first, as a cheap hack. you'd have to stop processing `OnPaint` for the duration though, or you'll get some visual glitching while it occurs. i think i used `SetCurrentCellAddressCore(columnIndex, rowIndex, False, False, True)` for something similar. hmm, grid will prob go black if you don't process `OnPaint` though :\

Comment: hmm on second thought, `SuspendLayout()` might do the trick, but not sure if a cell/row selection triggers a layout change if it has to scroll the list. in any case, you could `Hide()` the grid instead, then `Show()` it when done.

Comment: When I set the CurrentCell to some cell on the last row, it *does* set the current cell, but it doesn't scroll all thew way down to display it.  So that doesn't open up the scrollbar's range of values.  I've tried quite a few things like that.

Comment: lol, didn't see that one coming :D haha. hmmm, that sounds like a problem indeed.

Comment: this is all by design.  users cannot possibly consume thousands of rows of data at a time, so it is delivered to you as you need it. Even the Access UI works like this with large data sets. It doesnt know how much there is until it gets to the end, so it updates the Scrollbar incrementally. If it did deliver all the data to you *en masse* you'd be crying about performance and lagging.

Comment: The form allows the users to filter on various criteria at this point and the default view is only displaying ~50 rows.  The grid is acting like 80% of the way down is the bottom and even setting the current cell to the bottom row doesn't force the display to the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried an other `AutoScaleMode` property value on your Form?

Comment: if you are applying the filter on the client (your form/dgv) all that data still needs to be delivered to you; filter the data via a query and less data will delivered and it will work more like what you want.

Comment: Also the Virtual Mode of the DataGridView may help.

Comment: @Plutonix, I just threw a top 100 into the sproc that feeds the form and it's behaving mostly the same.  That is, I can't get it to scroll to the bottom by setting .CurrentCell or .FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex to the bottom row.  But the collapsing scroll-bar as I approach the bottom from the top is greatly lessened, just because of the fewer cells.

Comment: @Larry, I'll go read about Virtual Mode.  There is no AutoScaleMode property, but I've played with the AutoScrollOffset and the various AutoSize features.

Comment: @clweeks The AutoScaleMode property is on the top container (usercontrol or form) of the DataGrid.

Comment: How many rows do you have? Is the data bounded to a data source? Any other properties of the DGV set? I cannot seem to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Moop, The number of rows varies (50-2000, so far), but it happens across the spectrum.  The effect is most annoying when I'm binding 2000 rows and want to scroll to the bottom quickly.  The DGV.DataSource is a DataTable filled from a SqlDataAdapter.  I have various properties of the grid set in the designer, but I don't think anything is non-standard (of course, that's maybe my problem) but I don't know how to enumerate them all...

Comment: @clweeks You can go to the Form Designer file (its called *.Designer.cs for c#) and look for this section http://pastebin.com/wQ8n7hRe to list out all the properties of your DGV

Comment: @Moop, you're my hero!  It's apparently the AutoSizeRowMode!  I'd swear I checked that before but when I change it from DisplayedCellsExcepHeaders to AllCells, the problem vanishes.  Damn, that's "easy" (once you know)!

Comment: @clweeks Yeah, i just noticed that property was causing the problem on my test program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a test program for this problem (written in C#, but should be applicable to VB). It assumes you have one `DataGridView` named dataGridView1.

The `AutoSizeRowsMode` property should be set to `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells` to avoid the problem you are facing.

```
        DataTable data = new DataTable("Example");
        data.Columns.Add("1");
        data.Columns.Add("2");
        data.Columns.Add("3");
        data.Columns.Add("4");

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            data.Rows.Add(new []
                {
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "LONG STRING THAT SHOULD WRAP TO MULTIPLE LINES",
                    "4"
                });
        }
        data.Rows.Add(new[]
                {
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "LONG STRING THAT SHOULD WRAP TO MULTIPLE LINES",
                    "Last Row!!!"
                });

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode =DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; 
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders; // Appears that this line should be `AllCells` to avoid the problem you are facing
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: The above sample works fine either way, except that it's slower using AllCells. Perhaps DGV has been fixed? I have the same problem, but my DGV is in Virtual mode (no DataSource) with thousands of rows, so it's VERY slow to have AutoSizeRowsMode set to AllCells (even if I override RowHeightInfoNeeded to try to do a fast estimate). Also, when I do this, setting FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex to a row near the bottom causes a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException with the msg: "Additional information: Value of '23061' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'."